# Facebook chat on message deleted

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Can the person who you are chatting with on Facebook delete both their message and your replies and also your messages?

Answer (score 1):

A person can delete the messages (sent and receive both) only from his/her inbox, but they cannot delete any message from someone else's inbox.